# If a function is continuous at certain point, is the following true?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given that a function, $f$, is continuous at say $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}||<\delta$ then $|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{a})|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, if we have that $|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{a})|>\epsilon$,  is it necessary that there are coordinates $x_i$ and $a_i$ such that $|x_i-a_i|>\delta$?

Comment: If $\lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert \gt \epsilon$ then $\lVert x - a \rVert \gt \delta$.

Comment: Right, but are there coordinates $x_i$ and $a_i$ such that $|x_i-a_i|>\delta$?

Comment: @UniformIntegrability If $\| \cdot \|$ is the euclidean norm then no. $\|(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})\| = \sqrt{2 + 3} > 2$. But both $|\sqrt{2}|, |\sqrt{3}| < 2$

Comment: @UniformIntegrability Your question has nothing to do with continuity! It only deals with the link between the norm and the coordinates, which depends on the chosen norm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I get You right, but if we have that for all $x$ with $||x-a||< \delta$ it is $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ and we then take an $\tilde{x}$ such that it is $|f(\tilde{x}) - f(a)|>\epsilon$ then it has to be $||\tilde{x}-a||>\delta$.

Comment: I modified my question slightly.

Comment: So this questions boils down to the question: If $||x-a||>\delta$ is there always an $i$ such that $|x_i -a_i|>\delta$. If the norm $|| - ||$ can be any norm You want, it should be fairly easy to create a counter example for this.